# Show that if $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are "median", then they are equivalent

Tags: logic

A group $\Sigma \subseteq WFF$ is called "median" if for every pair $\alpha,\beta \in WFF$:

$\Sigma \vDash \alpha \lor\beta$ OR $\Sigma \vDash \alpha \lor(\neg \beta)$

prove/disprove:
if $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are medians, then $\Sigma_1 \equiv \Sigma_2$

Pretty sure it's not true. I know that WFF is a median group, but can't even start to think about another median group that isn't equivalent to WFF.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440969/how-to-prove-the-these-claims-in-propositional-logic

Comment: @TankutBeygu did they ask the same question as me?

Comment: this is indeed not true. note that, if $\Sigma$ is any "complete" subset of WFF, in the sense that $\Sigma\models\phi$ or $\Sigma\models\neg\phi$ for every WFF $\phi$, then $\Sigma$ is a median. (why?) so you need only find two complete subsets that are not logically equivalent; can you see how to do this? (hint: use Zorn's lemma, for example)